# EF 6 and spatial type DbGeography on Windows Azure

Tags: entity-framework, azure-sql-database

Have spent a couple of very frustrating days now trying to get the spatial type DbGeography to work on Windows Azure. I have a Windows Azure project with a Webrole where I use the DbGeography.Distance() method to calculate distances. Works lika a charm on my local computer but once published to Azure I get the exception:

```
Search spa  failed message: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.BadImageFormatException: An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.GLNativeMethods.GeodeticDistance(GeoMarshalData g1, GeoMarshalData g2, EllipsoidParameters ellipsoidParameters, Double& result)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.GLNativeMethods.GeodeticDistance(GeoData g1, GeoData g2, EllipsoidParameters ellipsoidParameters)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography.STDistance(SqlGeography other)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlSpatialServices.Distance(DbGeography geographyValue, DbGeography otherGeography)
   at System.Data.Entity.Spatial.DbGeography.Distance(DbGeography other)
   at DataAccess.Util.DistanceHelper.GetDistanceDictionary(DbGeography spaLocation)
   at MvcWebRole.Controllers.SpaController.SearchSpa(String searchString)
```

I have followed the blog post http://alastaira.wordpress.com/2011/08/19/spatial-applications-in-windows-azure-redux-including-denali/ adding reference to Sql.Server.Types and SqlServerSpatial.dll, msvcp100.dll and msvcr100.dll. Thist actually worked with EF5 and an Azure Website project but not now when I upgraded to EF6 and a Cloud service project :(

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I've got the same problem...

Answer (score 1):

The System.BadImageFormatException means you are deploying the wrong version of the native assembly (x86 vs x64).

We've published a NuGet package to make this easier - check out this post for details http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2013/12/09/microsoft-sqlserver-types-nuget-package-spatial-on-azure.aspx.